# arping with mac address fails

Tags: ping

I cannot get `arping` to run if I give a MAC address.
If I use IP address, it works fine.

Does anybody know what the problem is?

1.

```
arping -i <ifname> xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
arping: Unable to get the IPv4 address of interface <ifname>:
arping: libnet_get_ipaddr4(): ioctl(): Cannot assign requested address
arping: Use -S to specify address manually.
```

2.

```
arping -i brlan xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
arping: libnet_init(LIBNET_LINK, brlan): libnet_check_iface() ioctl: No such device
```

Comment: arping takes an IP address as a parameter, not a MAC address.

Comment: @RonTrunk portable Arping works with both. iputils-arping only works with IP addresses. Author obviously uses portable arping (key givaway is mention of libnet. iputils-arping doesn't use libnet)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. In order for arping to be able to send an ICMP echo request (what it does when pinging MAC addresses) it needs to put in a source address in that IP packet. The error message says that the `<ifname>` interface has no IP address. Your options are to give it one, or do what it says and use -S.
2. libnet (and therefore arping) thinks that the interface `brlan` doesn't exist. Are you sure that it does? (run `ip l l`)

If the interface in (1) has an address, or you *do* have an interface called `brlan`, then file a bug with how to reproduce at https://github.com/ThomasHabets/arping/issues